# Unable to connect SQLEXPRESS with Laravel 5.6

Tags: php, sql-server, laravel, ssms, sqlsrv

I'm trying to connect Laravel 5.6 to my SQLEXPRESS.

When I try to migrate tables from Laravel to SQL, I am getting this error:

> SQLSTATE[08001]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server]TCP
> Provider: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. (SQL: select * from sysobjects where type = 'U' and name = migrations)

I have installed the sqlsrv extionsion to php and tested it:

```
<?php
$serverName = "MYNAME\\SQLEXPRESS"; 

$connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"Portal", "UID"=>"sa", "PWD"=>"mySecretPwd");
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);

if( $conn ) {
     echo "Connection established.<br />";
}else{
     echo "Connection could not be established.<br />";
     die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}
?>
```

The connection is successfully established.

I also see the extension in the phpinfo();

But if switch to Laravel 5.6 with this settings:

my env:

```
DB_CONNECTION=sqlsrv
DB_HOST=MYNAME\\SQLEXPRESS
DB_PORT=1433
DB_DATABASE=Portal
DB_USERNAME=sa
DB_PASSWORD=mySecredPwd
```

my config/database:

```
'default' => env('DB_CONNECTION', 'sqlsrv'),

 'connections' => [

        .....

        'sqlsrv' => [
            'driver' => 'sqlsrv',
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', 'MYNAME\\SQLEXPRESS'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '1433'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8',
            'prefix' => '',
        ],

    ],
```

I'm getting an error.
My serverconfigurations manager looks like this:

[image]

I can also connect with SQL Server Management Studio 2017.

Comment: I assume it's a typo, but you have the DB_DATABASE parameter set to `forge` when it should be `Portal`.

Comment: @JacobH: That's just the default value if no value exists in `.env`.

Comment: Well that seems completely backwards, to provide a default value as a parameter to overwrite settings stored elsewhere. Anyway, maybe try without the instance?

Comment: Can you establish a connection with $serverName = "MYNAME\\SQLEXPRESS,1433" with your working PHP script?

Comment: @Zhorov. If i add the 1433 Port to the $serverName i get exactly the same error as in Laravel

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, find port number of the default instance:

- Check the port number. If you have MS SQL Server Management Studio, execute: `xp_readerrorlog 0, 1, N'Server is listening on'` in master database
- With command prompt (there will be a lot of rows, but you must analyze): `netstat -ano`

Possible solutions:

- Stop SQL Server Browser service and test again, always with port number. You can connect to the default instance of SQL Server with TCP/IP if it is running on port 1433
- Set SQL Server not to use dynamic ports and set the port number of default instance.
- Change config/database in Laravel to find a way to skip port number. I don't have experience with Laravel, but I think that you can try with `'port' => env('DB_PORT', null),`

How to configure server to listen to specific port:

- Open "Computer Management\Services\SQL Server Configuration Manager".
- Expand "SQL Server Network Configuration\Protocols for [instance name]" and double click "TCP/IP". In the "TCP/IP Properties" dialog box, on the IP Addresses tab, go to IPAll. Leave "TCP Dynamci port" empty. Set "TCP Port" to desired port number (could be default 1433).
- In the "SQL Server Services", double-click SQL Server Browser. In "Service" tab set "Start Mode" to "Manual".
- In the "SQL Server Services", double-click SQL Server Browser. In "Log On" stop service.
- In the "SQL Server Services", double-click SQL Server ([instance name]). In "Log On" restart service.
- Set client connection string to "server\instance,port" format.

Good starting points are:
[SQL Server Browser Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/configuration-manager/sql-server-browser-service?view=sql-server-2017) and [Configure a Server to Listen on a Specific TCP Port](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/configure-a-server-to-listen-on-a-specific-tcp-port?view=sql-server-2017)

I hope this can help you.

Comment: WOW ! thats helped me a lot. thank you. My port was wrong. I thought this is a default value 1433... my port is 61688. Do you know how can i change this to the default value ?

Comment: @GregOstry     I've updated the answer. This is my approach of configuring SQL Server.

Comment: It's too much help me. I have to set tcp port 1433 manually. It was not settings as default at all. THANKS AGAIN.