# Connect laravel 5.6 to SQL Server Express

Tags: sql-server, laravel, laravel-5, tcp, sql-server-2017-express

I'm trying to connect a laravel 5.6 project to SQL Server on Windows
I downloaded

> php_pdo_sqlsrv_71_ts.dll
>   and
>   php_sqlsrv_71_ts.dll

my phpinfo looks like this

[image]
[image]

But now when I try to run the migrations I get the error:

> Illuminate\Database\QueryException  : SQLSTATE[08001]:
>   [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server]TCP Provider: No se puede
>   establecer una conexión ya que el equipo de destino denegó
>   expresamente dicha conexión.

I already did the configuration following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50624986/unable-to-connect-sqlexpress-with-laravel-5-6) but still it's not working

My current config looks like this:

[image]
[image]

Comment: Please be advised this is an English website. Please translate your error messages accordingly. I did a google translate, but i will never know if it is 100% accurate. `A connection can not be established because the destination device explicitly denied such connection.`
Also have you tried everything in the solution given on the question you linked? Did you check the port number and such?

Comment: Make sure the instance is properly set on Laravel and that you have the correct driver configured (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18217843/908174))